# Null Pointer Exception while printing the array entries

Tags: java, arrays, jdbc, nullpointerexception

I made a class `Test` which counts the number of entries corresponding to the user id in the database (calling each entry an email). I used `11120059` as id and number of entries corresponding to this in the database is 2. The output of `countMail` function is working perfectly but because i am returning an array from `getMail()` function and taking it into new array, it is showing me null pointer exception. Please help I am stuck in middle of this. The code is:

```
package src.service;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import model.Email;
import model.User;

public class Test {

public int countMail(User user){

    try{

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

        // Get a connection to the database
        Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chillmaarodb", "root", "rsystems");

        PreparedStatement myStatement = myConn.prepareStatement("select * from complaints where RID=? ORDER BY date desc");


        myStatement.setString(1, user.getId());

        ResultSet rs = myStatement.executeQuery();

        int count=0;

        while(rs.next())
        {
        count++;
        }

        return count;
    }

    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;

}

public Email[] getMail(User user){

    try{

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

        // Get a connection to the database
        Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chillmaarodb", "root", "rsystems");

        PreparedStatement myStatement = myConn.prepareStatement("select * from complaints where RID=? ORDER BY date desc");


        myStatement.setString(1, user.getId());

        ResultSet rs = myStatement.executeQuery();

        Home home= new Home();

        int length = home.countMail(user);

        Email[] mail = new Email[length];

        int i=0;

        while(rs.next())
        {
        mail[i].setMessage((String) rs.getString(5));
        mail[i].setTitle((String) rs.getString(4)); 
        mail[i].setSender((String) rs.getString(2));
        mail[i].setReceiver((String) rs.getString(1));
        i++;
        }

        return mail;

        }
    catch (Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    Email[] dummyMail = new Email[1];

    return dummyMail;



}

public static void main(String[] args){

    Test test = new Test();

    User user = new User();

    user.setId("11120059");

    System.out.println(test.countMail(user));

    Email[] email = test.getMail(user);

    for (int i=0 ; i<test.countMail(user) ; i++){

        System.out.println(email[i].getSender());

    }


}

}
```

And the output is:

```
2 

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at src.service.Test.getMail(Test.java:73)
    at src.service.Test.main(Test.java:107)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at src.service.Test.main(Test.java:111)
```

Comment: Use `select count(*) from complaints where RID=?` to count the number of matching records for starters, you won't need the `while (rs.next())` statement, as it will  only return a single row/column result

Comment: Please add the line numbers to the listing.

Comment: I didnt get you TeasingDart

Comment: `home.countMail(user);` isn't the same as `test.countMail(user);`...?

Comment: And MadProgrammer, rs.next() will give me next entries too right? Its in the beginning of the table first then goes down one by one until rs.next is true and i am taking those values in an array. The point is it is counting the emails by the countMail function but something is wrong with sending the array as return type and taking it in another array.

Comment: mad programmer, the home and test java files are exactly the same thats why it isnt showing error in my machine. You read it as test.countMail(user)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write `Email[] mail = new Email[length];` you create an array of given length which contains null references. You cannot automatically create all the objects for that array by this command. Add `mail[i] = new Email()` statement:

```
    Email[] mail = new Email[length];

    int i=0;

    while(rs.next())
    {
    mail[i] = new Email(); // or use appropriate constructor parameters
    mail[i].setMessage((String) rs.getString(5));
    mail[i].setTitle((String) rs.getString(4)); 
    mail[i].setSender((String) rs.getString(2));
    mail[i].setReceiver((String) rs.getString(1));
    i++;
    }
```

Also note that when you create a `dummyMail` array, it's also an array with single `null`-reference, the `Email` object is not created there as well. Probably you need:

```
Email[] dummyMail = new Email[] {new Email()};
```